# What to do if op self-answers via a comment?

Tags: discussion, answers, comments

I have tried to search through meta for this question, but so far haven't found what I am about to ask so apologies if this is a duplicated topic.  Recently, I noticed a question where a user had self-answered via a comment and there were zero answers given.  The comments between the op and one other person didn't add anything to the question before the op posted a final comment of "ssue Solved,Reason Behind was due to custom style".

So there is a question, with a commented answer (not an actual answer), that will most likely never be touched again due to its specific question.  I flagged it as needing mod intervention, though I think I suggested it was closed since I felt it would never be answered again since the specific problem was uniqe to the authors code. In reality, maybe it should have had the comment promoted to an accepted answer.

What should be done with that post?

Comment: Flag for closure: off-topic, non-reproducible.

Comment: Don't fret about an answer if the question is no good to begin with. Agreed with flagging it.

Comment: Well, that isn't actually a "self-answer", only a status update with something that is pretty useless for everybody except OP. The usual way would be to provide a community wiki answer containing that OP (or any other user wrote) as the answer into the comments, but "Reason Behind was due to custom style" isn't an answer worth to be kept. So yivi is correct, flag for closure.

Comment: OK, in this case it would be as yivi suggest so I'll use that in the future.  If the comment actually gave a decent answer via the comment, what would I do then?

Comment: If the both the answer and question were decent enough, you can post your own answer using the comment's information, giving credit where credit is due.

Comment: Thanks for that will take it under advisement. Just noticed my question was a duplicate of another, as I suspected, though I never saw that in my searches :)

Comment: You _can_ mark as community wiki when leaving an answer. I do this for people who have updated their question with an answer. I move the answer out, post as an answer but mark as community wiki as I don't want the credit nor the responsibility. I also usually leave a note stating that I've moved the answer from x. I would then flag the comment (custom reason explaining what you have done) so a mod can remove.